# (iPhone)URL formatting question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, formatting

I am trying to format a URL but am getting a bug out of it. My code is below.

```
NSString *twitterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/?status=My%20score%20is:%i%20and%20CharsPerMin%20is:%@", currentScore, charPerMin.text];
```

When calling the method it doesn't do a thing. I think the issue is with `%20`. `%20` is being used to space each word in the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape your `%` signs by doubling them:

```
NSString *twitterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/?status=My%%20PracticeTyper%%20score%%20is:%i%%20and%%20CharsPerMin%%20is:%@", currentScore, charPerMin.text];
```